# How to find the length of the edge of a pyramid, knowing the length of the base and the ratio of the height to this side?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

How to find the edge length of a regular four-sided pyramid if the side of the base is 10 cm and the ratio of the height of the pyramid to this side is 1.618 to the power of 3/2?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a = base side length
e = edge length
h = height

```
Clear[a, e, h]

{e, h} = {e, h} /. 
   First@Solve[{e == Sqrt[h^2 + (a/Sqrt[2])^2], 
      h/a == GoldenRatio^(3/2)}, {e, h}] /. a -> 10
```

$\left\{5 \sqrt{2 \left(2 \sqrt{5}+5\right)},\frac{5 \left(\sqrt{5}+1\right)^{3/2}}{\sqrt{2}}\right\}$

> (* {21.7625, 20.5817} *)

---

*Visualization:*

```
pyr = Pyramid[{{0, 0, 0}, {a, 0, 0}, {a, a, 0}, {0, a, 0}, {a/2, a/2, 
     h}}] /. a -> 10
a = 10;
Graphics3D[{
  Opacity[0.2, Lighter@Yellow], pyr
  , Red, AbsolutePointSize[8]
  , Point@{a/2, a/2, 0}  (* center, base *)
  , Black, Dashed, Thick, Line[{{a/2, a/2, 0} , {a/2, a/2, h} }]
  }
 , Axes -> True
 , Lighting -> {"Ambient", White}
 ]
```

[image]

---

*Check:*

```
MeshPrimitives[pyr, 1] // Map[RegionMeasure]
```

> {10., 21.7625, 21.7625, 10., 21.7625, 10., 21.7625, 10.}

```
{e, h/10, GoldenRatio^(3/2)} // N
```

> {21.7625, 2.05817, 2.05817}

Answer (score 1):

If you know the points

```
pts = {{0, 0, 0}, {a, 0, 0}, {a, a, 0}, {0, a, 0}, {a/2, a/2, h}}
```

side lengths follow  to

```
Map[Sqrt[# . #] &[pts[[-1]] - #] &, Most[pts]]
(*{Sqrt[a^2/2 + h^2], Sqrt[a^2/2 + h^2], Sqrt[a^2/2 + h^2], Sqrt[a^2/2 + h^2]} *)

side=%[[1]] /.h->a GoldenRatio^(3/2) //FullSimplify[#,a>0]&
(*Sqrt[5/2 + Sqrt[5]] a*)
```

Comment: @syed Thanks for your hint, I deleted the unwanted answer.